# I need help to find a 'which way' style book featuring an item named 'little gaia'

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, choose-your-own-adventure

I had a 'which way' style book. You created your character first. And one item in the book is 'little gaia'. The book was sadly water damaged in transit so I've forgotten the title. I have tried looking on amazon for it but need its title. Anyone else remember this book?

Comment: These are generally referred to as gamebooks or CYOA (Choose Your Own Adventure)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art? How did you create your character, did you roll dice?

Comment: Thank you Valorum. The picture woke my memory. In my mind it was a 'which way' book that's probably why I couldn't find it.

Comment: @acesecure - [Always a pleasure.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the gamebook [*Heart of Ice*](https://tropedia.fandom.com/wiki/Heart_of_Ice) by Dave Morris.

There are multiple references to an item named "*Little Gaia*".

> You touch the red button. The box produces a prolonged hum which rises in tone and then ends with a bleep. ‘Ready,’ says a synthetic feminine voice from the speaker. Taken aback for a moment, you lean closer and gingerly speak to the box. ‘Er… ready for what?’ ‘Explain,’ says the box crisply. ‘Your query was unspecific.’ ‘Is this a radio? Who am I talking to?’ ‘I am a miniature facsimile of the Global Artificial Intelligence program,’ replies the box. ‘Gaia? But Gaia is crazy.’ ‘I was loaded with Gaia’s program prior to virus infection. I am able to model the thinking of the Gaia system at a reduced rate owing to my limited memory capacity, which now stands at 512 gigabytes.’ ‘What can you tell me about the Heart of Volent?’ ‘Nothing. No such information has been loaded into my memory.’ The device has an annoyingly smug little voice. **All the same, if it has even a fraction of Gaia’s intelligence then it may be useful. Record on your Adventure Sheet that you now possess Little Gaia**
>
> [image]